# Show that Q = S/θ is a pivotal quantity, and use this to provide a 95% upper confidence limit for θ

Tags: statistics, absolute-value, maximum-likelihood, confidence-interval

Consider a sample $X_1$, . . . , $X_n$ from the pdf
$f_X(x; θ)$ = $\frac{|x|}{θ^2}$$I_{(−θ,θ)}$(x).

We've already found that $S=max(|X_{1:n}|,|X_{n:n}|)$ is sufficient for θ.
Where $|X_{1:n}|$ denotes the absolute value of the smallest order statistic and $|X_{n:n}|$ denotes the absolute value of the largest order statistic.

The problem answering this question lies with the absolute value signs.

The question is:
Show that $Q = \frac{S}{θ}$ is a pivotal quantity, and use this to provide a 95% upper confidence limit for θ.

Comment: Have you tried computing the distribution of $Q$?  If not, try it.  If so, show what you have done.

Comment: I've tried, but cannot get by a good answer... I think I have to compute the distribution of |Xi| first.